# dynamically update html table in flask

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

so I have this pseudo search engine implemented using flask and Ajax, everything is working fine and the results show up at the end of a table for each keyup event.
this is the code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const search = document.querySelector("#search");
  if (search !== null)
  {
      search.onkeyup = () => {
          console.log(search.value); //checking for keyup events on search
          get_results(search.value);
      };
  }
});
function get_results(query)
{
    if (query === null)
    {
        return []
    }
    if (query !== "")
    {
        fetch(`/search/${query}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result); //works
            var x = 0;
            let table = document.getElementById('resulting');
            result.forEach(query => {
                console.log(query);
                const tr = document.createElement('tr');
                const td1 = document.createElement('td');
                let name = document.createTextNode(query.user_id)
                td1.appendChild(name);
                tr.appendChild(td1);
                table.appendChild(tr);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

the problem is that each time It gets a keyup event the results get added in rows at the end of the previous results while what I want to achieve is to display the table with just the results for the current query.

Comment: Empty the table before the `result.forEach()` loop.

Comment: `table.innerHTML = ''`